# Vertical spilts and folding in gvim

Tags: vim

I have problems with automated splits and folding.  In my ~/.gvimrc file, at the very end, I have the command `vsplit`, so that when I'm using gvim as opposed to vim, it opens with two panes.  The problem occurs when I open a file that would normally be folded via the command line, as in `gvim example.cpp`.  This opens the example.cpp file in two panes; however, the first pane is folded while the second is not.  It's a minor annoyance, but I wondered if anyone had a suggestion to get the second (or all) buffers to be folded when the window first appears.

If it makes a difference, I use `set foldmethod=indent` in my ~/.vimrc file, and my version is 7.1.

Answer (score 1):

this is very strange, it also happens here, I'm guessing there must be a bug because other settings are valid on the second pane, except for the `'foldmethod'` setting.

Anyway, I found an easy workaround. I have this at the end of my `.vimrc` and what you are looking for now works on my vim:

```
set foldmethod=indent
set sw=2
set tw=2

vsplit +edit
```

Now when I open a file, the window is split in two and both are folded correctly.

The workaround is executing the ex command `:edit` on the second pane so that the missing settings (although it seems that only `'foldmethod'` is missing) are reloaded. That's what the `+edit` after the `vsplit` does.

Hope this resolves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Jorge.  Unfortunately, with gvim adding this causes an error output to the console, and I need to hit enter to have vim continue processing.  After that, it comes up with both folded, but the intermediate error is really a bummer.  You did make me realize that I can "bufdo e" to reload all my files, which reapplies the folds, if I really want to.

Comment: I do not get any error at all with GVim, what error are you getting?